# Can't change startup programs in Startup Application Preferences

Tags: startup, preferences

I opened and changed startup programs in Startup Application Preferences.
Then after reboot the preferences didn't change, they are the same as it was before.
Why I can't change nothing and how to really setup Startup Application Preferences? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like a permission problem, you can try this (from a terminal):

```
sudo chown [username]:[username] -R ~/.config
```

If it doesn't help, try to start the "Startup Application Preferences" from a terminal using this command:

```
gnome-session-properties
```

You might see relevant error messages there. If the output looks useless to you, you might post it here.

Comment: I've got this message after unchecked some application: WARNING **: Could not save /home/megas/.config/autostart/deja-dup-monitor.desktop file. So the SAP(startup application preferences) can't change another's setting. How to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, after your first command it works. Thanks

Comment: Find this kind of issues with `find . \! -user $USER -print # -exec sudo chown $USER:$USER "{}" +`. Remove the `#` to fix them